# How to identify the element with the href attribute using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a problem with select on href

```
<a id="1 - GovSearch" name="1 - GovSearch" title="Population and Immigration Authority" 
href="https://www.gov.il/en/Departments/population_and_immigration_authority" class="content-title 
first-result" ng-class="{ 'first-result': $first }">
 <!-- ngIf: item.Extension -->
 <span ng-class="item.SubTitle ? 'pipe-after':''" class="ng- 
     binding"> Population and Immigration Authority </span>
                                        <!-- ngIf: item.SubTitle -->
                                    </a>
```

I tried to make with *linktext* and getting error:

```
element.FindElement(By.LinkText("Population and Immigration Authority")).Click();
```

Getting this error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: 'stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit unconclusive from the details why you would see a *StaleElementReferenceException*. However, the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element and within the child `<span>` tag of the `<a>` element. So you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("a[id$='GovSearch'][name$='GovSearch'][title='Population and Immigration Authority'] span.ng-binding"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[@title='Population and Immigration Authority']//span[@class='ng-binding' and contains(., 'Population and Immigration Authority')]"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: i tried to ran but getting error with the xpth   Message: 
    Test method hw.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@title='Population and Immigration Authority']//span[@class='ng-binding' and contains(., ' – Population and Immigration Authority')]"}
      (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
  Stack Trace:

Comment: @danielshmushmayovich Did you try the _CssSelector_? However there seems to bean extra **–** within _contains(., ' – Population and Immigration Authority')_

Answer (score 0):

This error is  usually caused when element has changed or removed because of something that user has tried to do. You can try catching exception and then click again

```
try {
    element.FindElement(By.LinkText("Population and Immigration Authority")).Click();
}
catch(org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException ex)
{
   element.FindElement(By.LinkText("Population and Immigration Authority")).Click();
}
```

Webdriver internally uses `getElementAt` method and a unique id  called `UUID` to locate elements. Anytime this `UUID` changes for an element because of any reason and the call that user is making refers to old `UUID`, `getElementAt`  method throws exception. You can also see exception referring to `fxdriver.cache.getElementAt` method.  You can find official explanation of this error [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/StaleElementReference)